# How to force reorganization of a priority_queue?

Tags: c++11, priority-queue

I have a `priority_queue` that contains a `vector` with some objects.

```
std::priority_queue<std::shared_ptr<Foo>, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Foo>>, foo_less> foo_queue;
```

It has a `foo_queue` function that will order the `priority_queue`.

Now, from outside of the `priority_queue`, I want to change some object value that must influenciate the ordering of the `priority_queue`.

**My question is:**

How can I set some kind of "*refresh*" that will trigger the `priority_queue` to run the `foo_queue()` in order to keep it orderes all the time?

Comment: "influenciate", not quite a word, but I like it! Why not just remove the object, update it's value, and add it back in? Oh, wait, that's probably not as easy as it seems....

Comment: lol accidentally I've mixed up my native language with English...ops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your own priority queue using the standard heap algorithms and a
vector. When you want to change a key, find and remove that value from
the underlying vector and call make_heap on the vector. Alter the key and then
push it back onto the heap. So the cost is a linear search of the vector
to find the value and a call to make_heap (which I think is also linear).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template <class T, class Container = std::vector<T>,
          class Compare = std::less<T> >
class my_priority_queue {
protected:
    Container c;
    Compare comp;
public:
    explicit my_priority_queue(const Container& c_  = Container(),
                            const Compare& comp_ = Compare())
        : c(c_), comp(comp_)
    {
        std::make_heap(c.begin(), c.end(), comp);
    }
    bool empty()       const { return c.empty(); }
    std::size_t size() const { return c.size(); }
    const T& top()     const { return c.front(); }
    void push(const T& x)
    {
        c.push_back(x);
        std::push_heap(c.begin(), c.end(), comp);
    }
    void pop()
    {
        std::pop_heap(c.begin(), c.end(), comp);
        c.pop_back();
    }
    void remove(const T& x)
    {
        auto it = std::find(c.begin(), c.end(), x);
        if (it != c.end()) {
            c.erase(it);
            std::make_heap(c.begin(), c.end(), comp);
        }
    }
};

class Foo {
    int x_;
public:
    Foo(int x) : x_(x) {}
    bool operator<(const Foo& f) const { return x_ < f.x_; }
    bool operator==(const Foo& f) const { return x_ == f.x_; }
    int get() const { return x_; }
    void set(int x) { x_ = x; }
};

int main() {
    my_priority_queue<Foo> q;

    for (auto x: {7, 1, 9, 5}) q.push(Foo(x));
    while (!q.empty()) {
        std::cout << q.top().get() << '\n';
        q.pop();
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

    for (auto x: {7, 1, 9, 5}) q.push(Foo(x));
    Foo x = Foo(5);
    q.remove(x);
    x.set(8);
    q.push(x);
    while (!q.empty()) {
        std::cout << q.top().get() << '\n';
        q.pop();
    }
}
```

Comment: It was easier than it might look since the C++ standard document contains an example implementation like this! I didn't put in all the details, but if you need more functionality (ctors, etc) you can look there. I was trying to see if we could get ahold of the underlying vector in the standard implementation but I couldn't see how to do that (although I don't see why it would be impossible, so I may be missing something).